# Automatable code analysis tools C#

Tags: c#, automation, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a code analysis tool for **C#** that can be **automatable**, so developers can run it on their local machines, as well as **integratable** in a **CI** server.

It should be possible to establish a **baseline**, since the project I want to configure it already contains lots of LOCs.

If possible... **open source**, but this is not really a must. I looked at NDepend, but, despite cool, it is waaaay too expensive.

Visual Studio integration is just a "good to have" feature.

I've looked at **Code Analysis of Visual Studio** but it doesn't provide any way to automate it or establish a baseline. I used **FxCop** in other projects, but it does not exist anymore as a stand-alone tool; it's been included in Code Analysis and it cannot be automated.

Does anybody know a tool like this?